# Why do children call themselves by their name?

Tags: learning

Why is that young children call themselves by their first name when referring to themselves? This question is similar to [Speaking in the third person](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2320/1328); however, young children do not understand the connotations of speaking in the third person.

My fiance's cousin who is six refers to herself as ゆりちゃん. Is the only reason she calls herself by her own name because everyone calls her ゆりちゃん when talking to her? When do children stop referring to themselves in the third person and why?

Comment: Are you asking why they do not use the last name or why they do not use personal pronouns? The title implies the former but the text the latter.

Comment: @sawa: I see what you mean. I changed the title, and I'm interested in why they do not use personal pronouns. Especially when the family around them does use them.

Comment: I suspect that this is related to the concept of [Identity Formation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_formation)

Comment: Here is a similar question: [When is it appropriate to refer to yourself using your name, rather than 私 (or others)?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5388/when-is-it-appropriate-to-refer-to-yourself-using-your-name-rather-than-%E7%A7%81-or-o/5390#5390)

Comment: Reminds me of 「さっちゃんはね・・・だけどちっちゃいから自分のことさっちゃんて呼ぶんだよ・・・」http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6VX6koVoKig

Comment: @Chocolate That's exactly how she sounds.

Comment: When do children stop referring to themselves in the third person and why?>>> I didn't call myself by my name or nickname when I was 6, but some of my friends still did. I remember that when we were starting to go to elementary school at age 6~7, adults (their parents and kindergarten teachers) told them to get rid of this habit. Calling yourself by your name/nickname/~~chan is normally regarded "childish" (and/or "cute"...). Adults said that we should call ourselves by "私、僕" at school.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@JesseGood's answer is correct, but just to add to it:

Not only will other people refer to kids by their name, they will often also refer to *themselves* by title when speaking to them. I.e. their mother/father will likely refer to themselves as "お母さん/お父さん" or "ママ/パパ" and their teacher to him/herself as "先生" when speaking to them. They might not hear personal pronouns much at all in their daily lives.

Thus, it's not surprising that kids learn that people have a label which is used independently from who is using it. Kids have to learn to use pronouns *at all*, which is quite different from the problem of learning to use I/you *correctly*, which seems to be common in languages where pronouns are more commonly used.

Comment: Also, it's common to call a young boy as "boku (僕)." In the end, he associates "boku" like his name with himself, and ends up saying it to mean "I".

Comment: @Axioplase Wow, is that really common? This is the first time I've heard it. What about girls then?

Comment: @Chris: yes, I think it's very common. For girls, I think you mostly use the child's name, or お嬢ちゃん (ojouchan).

Answer (score 4):

According, to the wikipedia article for [illeism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illeism):

> Young children in Japan commonly refer to themselves by their own name
>   (a habit probably picked from their elders who would normally refer to
>   them by name, this is due to the normal Japanese way of speaking where
>   referring to another in the third person is considered more polite
>   rather than using the Japanese words for "you", like Omae[3]) though
>   as the children grow older they normally switch over to using first
>   person references. Japanese Idols also may refer to themselves as so
>   to give off the feeling of childlike cuteness.

Which I think has *some* truth to it. In Japanese it is more common to refer to children by their name than other languages and also since young women also use it, there is a chance that the child may pick it up by seeing the usage from other people. Also, my own personal opinion is that Japanese is very complicated when it comes to first person and third person pronouns, and that is why children will use their names to avoid having to worry about it. Women generally will stop at an early age although some women might continue using it even up to there early thirties (although people around them might detest it). I think for men, you will only see the usage in very young children (preschool or earlier).

Also, I think it should be known that while English speaking countries find this usage very strange, it is common in other languages such as Thai also.